# Fillin jqGrid depend on url parameter

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I use c#, mvc, jqGrid and Trirand.Web.Mvc
I have two pages, on the first page a grid with Roles and on the second Grid with rights. Depend on the selected role on the first page I would like to redirect user to the second page (for link /{controller}/{action}/{id}) and depend on {id} fill in the second grid with rights.
I implemented some of the code. This is the default method and here I have correct id from url

```
public ActionResult RightList(int id = 0)
{
  int roleID = id;
  var gridModel = new RightJQGridModel();
  RightJQGrid_SetUpGrid(gridModel.RightJQGrid);
  // Pass the custmomized grid model to the View
  return View(gridModel);
}
```

but later cshtml file starts to render and JavaScript sends the second request to the method RightJqGrid_DataRequested() to fill in the grid with Rights. 
My problem is the second JavaScript request does not contains the RoleID.
I can find this id in the Request.UrlReferrer.ToString() but I need to pars it and from my point of view it is not correct.
Could you give me some tips? Am I doing right? What is the best strategy for the same cases?

Comment: Can you show the code on the cshtml with the jqgrid definition?

Comment: Maybe it is not very good example, but I think it should clarify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Roles:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> function redirectToRights() 
{ 
    var id = $('#jqGridRoles').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow'); 
    var _url = '@Url.Action("RightList", "Right", new { id = "_id" })';
    window.location.href = url.replace("_id", _id); 
} 
</script>
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Get, 
new { 
    name = "frmRoleList", 
    id = "frmRoleList" })) { @Html.Trirand().JQGrid(Model.RoleJQGrid, "jqGridRoles") 
}
```

Rights:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Get, 
new { name = "frmRightList", id = "frmRightList" }))
{
  @Html.Trirand().JQGrid(Model.RightJQGrid, "jqGridRights")
}
```